# Database model: How to design a multilanguage help system database?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I am a little bit stuck with this "simple" database design. Maybe someone has a better idea. I need to design a help system with the following requirements:

- a help content has a title
- a help content has a content
- a help content is multilanguage (title and content)
- a help content in english is mandatory
- a help content in english is always used as fallback when a content in a different language is not available
- a help content can be assigned to multiple categories

[image]

Seems to be a very simple model, but my question is the following

1) When english is the fallback language and always needs to be created first before other languages can be created, is it a good design to work with ParentId?

2) How can i query with the fallback language? I mean lets assume that the user has selected Spanish as his preferred language. But for Spanish some content does not exist in Spanish but in English only. How can i query for items which are existing in Spanish but return also items which have only English content without Spanish child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few comments on your diagram:

Your relationship cardinality (in the diagram only) for the connection between `HelpContent` and `HelpContent_Categories` is incorrect.  The *many* end of the relationship should be attached to the intersecting entity type (`HelpContent_Categories`).  The foreign key is in the right place, but the line is drawn incorrectly.

The cardinality between `HelpContent` and `Language` is incorrect. You are showing 1:1, but the cardinality should be 1:M.

Overall, I would approach these stated requirements differently.  I would have the mandatory English content be one table with all of the translations being a separate table that intersects with `Language`.  You could flatten such an arrangement into the tables you've shown using a `ParentId`, but that might be confusing.  It certainly doesn't use the schema to enforce your business rule that English is mandatory and all other languages are optional.

Consider this ERD:
[image: ERD]

The English content is in the `Category` and `HelpContent` tables.  All the translated values are in the intersection tables with `Language`.

To query for help in any given language, you OUTER JOIN the main/English table with the translation tables and then COALESCE the translated and English values together.  If the translation exists, then you get the translation.  If it doesn't exist, you get the English as a fallback.

I have to admit that it rubs me the wrong way to have two tables instead of one, but it does enforce your business rule with schema rather than extra code that has to be written and maintained.

Comment: Hi Joel. Thank you for the answer. Do i have it understood correctly that i have the main english content in the `Help Content` table and then have  the Id of the main english item and additionally the language id in the `Content Translation` table?

Comment: @STORM Yes.  The main English content is in the `HelpContent` table and the translated content is in the `ContentTranslation` table, along with a foreign key to `HelpContent` (e.g. HelpContentId) and a foreign key to `Language` (e.g. LanguageId or code, or whatever you're using)